# Положение колонок Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

```css
.col.col-xl-3 {background:red}
.col.col-xl-9 {background:black}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xl-3 order-xl-3 col-lg-6 order-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">///</div>
    <div class="col col-xl-9 order-xl-2 col-lg-12 order-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">///</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не смотря на то, что **3** первый, а **9** второй, **3** отображается не слева, а справа. Как исправить?

**P.s:** разверните фрагмент, чтобы увидеть пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы первой колонке задали `order-xl-3`, а второй `order-xl-2`.
Если хотите поменять местами:

```
<div class="col col-xl-3 order-xl-1 col-lg-6 order-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">///</div>
<div class="col col-xl-9 order-xl-2 col-lg-12 order-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">///</div>
```